# How can I have a powershell loop that echos echo on the same line?

Tags: sql, loops, powershell, formatting, echo

Currently I have the follow ps that reads a list of user names and then echos it.

The username file is the following

```
username1
username2
username3
```

The ps script is the following

```
$userNames = (Get-Content usernames.txt)# | Sort-Object
$userID=0
$userNames.Count
echo "FROM table WHERE (userID ='"
For ($i =1; $i -le ($userNames.Count - 1); $i++)
{
echo $userNames[$userID] "' OR userID='"
$userID++
}
echo $userNames[$userNames.Count - 1] "'"
```

I am hoping to get this to echo (and eventually write to a text file) all on the same line.

```
FROM table WHERE (userID = 'username1' OR userID = 'username2' OR userID = 'username3'
```

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
Write-Host "Blah" -NoNewLine
```

I would probably re-write the script like this to avoid having to use the `For...Loop`

```
$userNames = (Get-Content usernames.txt) | Sort-Object
$count = 0

Write-Host "FROM table WHERE (" -NoNewLine

$userNames |% {
    Write-Host "userID='$_'" -NoNewLine

    if(++$count -ne $userNames.Length){
        Write-Host " OR " -NoNewLine
    }
    else {
        Write-Host ")"
    }
}
```

This script will also take advantage of another nice feature of PowerShell, which is variable substitution in string literals. `For-EachObject` automatically sets `$_` to be the current object during the iteration, and PowerShell will automatically parse variables in string literals and substitute their values.

Also... **I just realized the entire thing can be reduced to the following:**

```
$userNames = (Get-Content usernames.txt) | Sort-Object |% { "'$_'" }

Write-Host "FROM table WHERE UserID in ($([String]::Join(",",$userNames)))"
```

Which will produce the following query:

```
FROM table WHERE UserID in ('username1','username2','username3')
```

This is a much more pleasant script *and* query in my opinion :)

Comment: this is exactly the trick i was looking for. it does print userID='username1 ' now. how can i get rid of the space after the 1?